# in programming what does this mean

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming and the tutorial types the following code which generates a page full of code. What does this code do, i use sublime text

```
                   div#container>div#main>ul#nav>li*4>lorem
```

Comment: It's called [*Zen Coding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding). It's not aimed at beginners, please find a tutorial that teaches plain HTML first.

Comment: It's called emmet now. http://docs.emmet.io/ In Sublimetext, there is a plugin that lets you type like this which will do this:

 1. make div with id attribute equal to container.
 2. make another div inside previous with id = main.
 3. and so on till it reaches li it creates 4 li
 4. it replaces lorem with dummy text that means nothing but is useful because it can be used to see what text would look like.

Comment: god calling it zencoding is misguided. once, i thought the plugin was discontinued and searched for like 20-30 minutes going back and forth between links.

Answer (score 1):

It's zen coding (emmet now), generate html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ullam laudantium ipsum hic impedit illo quas officia ab adipisci obcaecati dolore qui dolores perferendis id repellat ipsam nam modi provident!</li>
            <li>Voluptatibus nisi assumenda illum vero earum asperiores illo praesentium quis eius fugiat veniam facilis corporis quasi nostrum id expedita autem ad sequi saepe quas fugit! In veritatis odit tempora saepe.</li>
            <li>Odit earum quas necessitatibus quis aliquam doloremque totam eligendi harum vitae eius quia nihil similique recusandae doloribus excepturi maiores blanditiis reiciendis. Magnam in id deleniti dolorem similique blanditiis exercitationem nam?</li>
            <li>Quod aliquid sed asperiores blanditiis repellendus consectetur fugit itaque eveniet obcaecati voluptates animi explicabo nesciunt nemo. Libero maiores sint. Corporis laborum illo modi impedit aliquam amet porro! Aperiam atque id.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can install it from package control http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control
, and here is emmet https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime